# List sharepoint files in a specific subfolder with Office365-REST-Python-Client

Tags: python, rest, sharepoint

I need to download all files from sharepoint in a group of subfolders, but I'm struggling to get the list of files to use the download Method.

I'm using the python library Office365-REST-Python-Client, specifically the enum_files_and_folders.py example.

The problem is my document library is too large. Then a want to enum only files in a specific subfolder.

My sharepoint structure is something like this:

https://mysite/shared documents/General/.../sheets/year/month

I want to download all xlsx files in sheets folder and subfolders, without transversing all document library structure.

Does anyone know a filter option ?

My current code is something like this:

```
doc_lib = contexto.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(relative_url)
items = doc_lib.items.select(["FileSystemObjectType"]).expand(["File", "Folder"]).get().execute_query()
arquivos_fluxo =[]
for item in items:  # type: ListItem
    if item.file_system_object_type != FileSystemObjectType.Folder:
        if "myfiles.xlsx" in item.file.serverRelativeUrl:
            print("File url: {0}".format(item.file.serverRelativeUrl))
            arquivos_fluxo.append(item.file.serverRelativeUrl)
```

Answer (score 3):

i encountered a similar problem. Here's the code that I use to retrieve all files from a subfolder:

```
def get_all_files_from_document_library(spo_site: str, folder_name: str) -> list:
    try:
        user_credentials = UserCredential(global_settings.SYSTEM_USER_SPO, secret.SYSTEM_USER_PWD)
        ctx = ClientContext(f"{global_settings.SHAREPOINT_BASE_URL}/sites/{spo_site}").with_credentials(user_credentials)
        files = ctx.web.get_folder_by_server_relative_url(folder_name).files
        ctx.load(files).execute_query()
        file_list = []
        for file in files:
            file_list.append({"Name": file.name, "ServerRelativeUrl": file.serverRelativeUrl})

    except:
        logging.error("Could not retrieve files from folder '%s/%s'", spo_site, folder_name)
        return None
    return file_list
```

I used the answers posted on [this](https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/issues/98) github issue as a reference.